# How to iterate over list of lists while passing each value in the lists into API and pausing after each list of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, api-design

I have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = [1,2,3, etc]
```

I can successfully iterate over this list and pass the IDs into an API. However the API breaks after certain point in regards to number of Ids I am passing.

I went ahead and broke the list into chunks of 50 using this code:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    # For item i in a range that is a length of l,
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        # Create an index range for l of n items:
        yield l[i:i+n]

a = list(chunks(lst, 50))
```

The `a` variable is list of list that looks like this:

```
[[1,2,3][4,5,6]]
```

How do I iterate over the list of list, passing individual Ids into the API code (below), while pausing the code for 10seconds after every chunk?

In addition, if the API breaks, is there anyway I can force the API to continue rest of the code ? Not a requirement for now, so this is optional.

API code:

```
lst1=[]
for i in lst:
    #print (row)
    url = 'url/Id={}'.format(i)
    r = requests.get(url).text
    lst1.append(xml_data1)
    #time.sleep(1)
    print(xml_data1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double `for` loop with use of the `sleep` function after execution of the inner loop. Here's an example:

```
lst1 = []
for chunk in a:
    for id in chunk:
        url = 'url/Id={}'.format(id)
        xml_data = requests.get(url).text
        lst1.append(xml_data)
     sleep(10) # will pause execution for 10 seconds
```

To answer your second question about how to continue execution if the API throws an error, you can use `try/except`. Code that might throw an error goes in the `try` block and if an error is thrown, execution moves to the `except` block, which specifies how to proceed. If you wrap your code in a function this can be made a bit easier.

I find it helpful to track the number of times you've tried calling for a specific `id` with a keyword argument that can be used for exponential backoff -- where you wait for longer amounts of time depending on how many times you've tried.

Here is an example building on the above code:

```
def get_data_on_id(id, try_num=1):
    url = 'url/Id={}'.format(id)
    try:
        return requests.get(url).text
    except:
        sleep(2**try_num) # exponential backoff
        return get_data_on_id(id, try_num=try_num + 1)

lst1 = []
for chunk in a:
    for id in chunk:
        xml_data = get_data_on_id(id)
        lst1.append(xml_data)
    sleep(10)
```

The code above is largely the same as the code before it, but the request logic is wrapped in the `get_data_on_id` function, which contains the `try/except` blocks. If an error is thrown when requesting the `url`, the function will wait for `2^try_num` seconds and then try again.

You might also want to `except` specific errors and handle them differently (or just to be explicit so you only `except` errors you are prepared to handle). Here are the docs on `try/except`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html